# IntelliJ custom data view equivalent for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

Does eclipse has something like the [Customize Data Views feature of IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/customize-data-views.html)?

I tried searching, but couldn't find such thing. Maybe it exists but with a very different name, so I couldn't find it.

Screenshot from IntelliJ:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the **Detail Formatters**.

https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/debug/ref-detail_formatters.htm?cp=1_4_2_0_4_0